# Woocommerce webhook Error: Delivery URL cannot be reached

Tags: java, json, wordpress, web-services

im traying to send the woocomerce checkout data to a java rest webservice, currently im testing the connection to the webservice so it only receives the data and prints it to the console

rest endpoint
http://75.98.169.122:9091/test/rest/SumaService/webHookMock
using soapui i can send data(string or json) and it works ok

ws code

```
 @POST
 @Path("/webHookMock")
 @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public String webHookMock(String res) throws JSONException {
     try {
         System.out.println(res);
          return res;
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
          return "Se produjo un error en la aplicacion";
      }
  }
```

im using webhooks from the woocomerce api, when I use a test url created from http://requestb.in/
 the webhook send the json data to the url, but i try using my url and i get the following message from woocomerce
Error: Delivery URL cannot be reached

why woocommerce cant reach my url?
is it a problem with the configuration of the webservice?

Comment: According to http://you.earth/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-webhook.php you can get this error when the status code is anything but 200. What status code do you get back in SoapUI?

Comment: this is from the RAW tab of the response on soap ui                                                                                              HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.1 JSP/2.3 (GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.0  Java/Oracle Corporation/1.8)
Server: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.0
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 18 Aug 2016 22:25:33 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

{"test":"from soap ui"}

Comment: i change the responce type to text/html                                                                     (@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML) )  , since from what i can tell its the only difference with the response from requestb.in , but still did not work

Comment: @Manuel: You have to make sure webhook URL is publicly accessible.

Comment: Was the problem because of the port number on here?